how to fix Qubes OS template search error
In Dom0 i can't download templates. In Qubes Template Manager an error:
Failed to fetch template list. Error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/etc/qubes-rpx/qubes.TemplateSearch'
I run Qubes on VM on Debian 12.
VM resources:
CPU 8
Memory 8.0 GiB
Storage limit: 32 GiB (Used 11 GB)
